# Cascade delete of model with GenericForeignKey without using GenericRelation

Tags: django, cascading-deletes, generic-foreign-key, django-generic-relations, generic-relations

I'm creating a reusable django app which includes a model with `GenericForeignKey` which I need to be cascade deleted.

This model may be attached to any other. I have no control over target model class as it is outside of the app. This means I can not add `GenericRelation` field to it and can't force user to add it as target might be in another third-party app.

Assuming we have such models (having NO control over `Post` and `PostGroup`):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey()

class PostGroup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(PostGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is there a way to delete `Tag` in case of `PostGroup` queryset is being deleted?

E.g. not only `post_group.delete()` but also `PostGroup.objects.delete()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pre_delete` signal to achieve this:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_delete) # add relevant sender to signal (not mandatory)
def post_group_deleted(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    # Query tags with the instance of PostGroup and delete them
    if isinstance(instance, Tag):
        return

    Tag.objects.filter(
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance),
        object_id=instance.pk
    ).delete()
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

> Unlike ForeignKey, GenericForeignKey does not accept an on_delete argument to customize this behavior; if desired, you can avoid the cascade-deletion by not using GenericRelation, and alternate behavior can be provided via the pre_delete signal.

Comment: I can not use `PostGroup` as it's outside of my app. It can be installed in other person's project and be attached any model there.

Comment: I edited your response to be actually working. Still, it's very ineffective as being called for each instance separately.

Comment: Your question say - delete `Tag` in case of `PostGroup` queryset is being deleted, so the signal should be for sender `PostGroup`

Comment: Read carefully pls. My question says I have NO control over Post or PostGroup. I can not import them as this is reusable app and these models are outside of it. Please remove sender so it will be at least working answer.

Comment: thanks. Actually there is no need to add relevant sender. As question says, I have no access to senders. I already tested it and this code works fine without sender at all. I will wait for the case if someone has more effective solution. If not, will mark it as correct one.